# I encountered when executing kubeadm init error issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I encountered as below when executing sudo kubeadm init
Help me~~

```
$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.24.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: E0605 10:35:34.973561   12491 remote_runtime.go:925] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
time="2022-06-05T10:35:34+09:00" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 66):

work around found here :
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4581

```
rm /etc/containerd/config.toml
systemctl restart containerd
kubeadm init
```

Comment: I don't know why you would remove the `config.toml` configuration. It clearly states in the issue that disabling the `cri` plugin via `disabled_plugins = ["cri"]` causes the issue.

Comment: @Xanmashi At the moment, deleting and commenting out `disabled_plugins = ["cri"]` has the same effect, as this is the only uncommented line in the `config.toml` file. But you are right that deleting the file instead of just commenting out the line may cause unexpected errors during future updates.

Comment: I followed user@k8s-master:~/$ sudo rm /etc/containerd/config.toml
user@k8s-master:~/$ sudo systemctl restart containerd
user@k8s-master:~/$ sudo kubeadm init still facing the issue

Comment: For more details
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4581

Comment: Even after commenting or deleting it is not working in my case for v1.26.1

Comment: It says, [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time="2023-02-01T16:50:16+05:30" level=fatal msg="validate service connection: CRI v1 runtime API is not implemented for endpoint \"unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock\": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService"

Comment: Same as @AbhishekDutta, I have no idea what else to try...